# Magento 2 : Get Data From Two Tables or Model

Tags: model, magento-2.1.3, join-table

I have created ui component and it works fine, I added data provider file and customized my getData function:-

```
public function getData() {
        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }


        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('qrcode' => $this->_resource->getTableName('w3solver_qrcode')),
                                               'e.entity_id = qrcode.product_id');

        // echo $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->__toString();
        // exit();

        $items = $this->getCollection()->toArray();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($items);
        exit();        
        return [
            'totalRecords' => $this->getCollection()->getSize(),
            'items' => array_values($items),
        ];
    }
```

When I try to print collection query it gives me correct output but $items is not giving me fields from second table. Can anyone help mw and let me know why I am not getting field from second table.

Comment: Use only join instead of joinLeft

Comment: put your collection join query before `if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }`

Comment: I have tried those step but it did not work

Comment: @PrincePatel when my requirement is to use leftjoin then why will i go for join only.

Comment: I have done it, toArray() is a function created in core file which is responsible for only fetching column from first table, don't know why but I just replaced it by my $this->getCollection()->getData(); and it works